# Printing Ansible Sub Variables through Debug

Tags: ansible

I am trying to print sub variables through Debug statement..

- debug: var=junction_detail_ret_obj -- working
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPBAC.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4cnA.png)

  "msg": {
          "active_worker_threads": "0", 
          "authz_rules": "no", 
          "basic_auth_mode": "ignore", 
          "boolean_rule_header": "no", 
          "client_ip_http": "insert", 
          "cookie_include_path": "no", 
          "delegation_support": "no", 
          "forms_based_sso": "disabled", 
          "fsso_config_file": "disabled", 
          "http_header_ident": "", 
          "insert_session_cookies": "yes", 
          "junction_cookie_javascript_block": "inhead", 
          "junction_hard_limit": "0 - using global value", 
          "junction_point": "/mga", 
          "junction_soft_limit": "0 - using global value", 
          "junction_type": "SSL", 
          "mutual_auth": "no", 
          "preserve_cookie": "no", 
          "remote_http_header": "", 
          "request_encoding": "", 
          "scripting_support": "yes", 
          "servers": [
              {
                  "case_sensitive_url": "no", 
                  "current_requests": "0", 
                  "http_port": "", 
                  "local_ip": "", 
                  ***"operation_state": "Online",*** 
                  "query_content_url": "", 
                  "query_contents": "unknown", 
                  "server_dn": "", 
                  "server_hostname": "", 
                  "server_port": "", 
                  "server_state": "running", 
                  "server_uuid": "", 
                  "total_requests": "802", 
                  "virtual_junction_hostname": "localhost", 
                  "windows_style_url": "no"
              }
          ], 
          "session_cookie_backend_portal": "yes", 
          "stateful_junction": "no", 
          "tfim_sso": "no", 
          "transparent_path_junction": "no"
      }
  }

I want to print "operation_state:Online"

```
- debug: msg='{{ junction_detail_ret_obj.data.servers.["operation_state"] }}'
```

This is not working Getting following error.

FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ junction_detail_ret_obj.data.servers.[\"operation_state\"] }}"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/pa8090/ipa_firstnet/report_junction_mga.retry

Comment: There's no key named `data` in your json. What you should be querying is
`junction_detail_ret_obj.servers[0].operation_state`

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working play. Try it out

```
---
- name: Json query play
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    #This task sets the fact about pool-names and creates a list var.
    - name: Set junction_detail_ret_obj fact
      set_fact:
        junction_detail_ret_obj: '{ "active_worker_threads": "0", "authz_rules": "no", "basic_auth_mode": "ignore", "boolean_rule_header": "no", "client_ip_http": "insert", "cookie_include_path": "no", "delegation_support": "no", "forms_based_sso": "disabled", "fsso_config_file": "disabled", "http_header_ident": "", "insert_session_cookies": "yes", "junction_cookie_javascript_block": "inhead", "junction_hard_limit": "0 - using global value", "junction_point": "/mga", "junction_soft_limit": "0 - using global value", "junction_type": "SSL", "mutual_auth": "no", "preserve_cookie": "no", "remote_http_header": "", "request_encoding": "", "scripting_support": "yes", "servers": [ { "case_sensitive_url": "no", "current_requests": "0", "http_port": "", "local_ip": "", "operation_state": "Online", "query_content_url": "", "query_contents": "unknown", "server_dn": "", "server_hostname": "", "server_port": "", "server_state": "running", "server_uuid": "", "total_requests": "802", "virtual_junction_hostname": "localhost", "windows_style_url": "no" } ], "session_cookie_backend_portal": "yes", "stateful_junction": "no", "tfim_sso": "no", "transparent_path_junction": "no" }'

    - name: Debug print operation state
      debug:
        msg: "operation_state:{{ junction_detail_ret_obj | from_json | json_query('servers[0].operation_state') }}"
...
```